# selecting multiple rows in one table with different fields

Tags: mysql

I have the following queries:

`SELECT count(id) from table_1 WHERE field_1 = 1`

`SELECT count(id) from table_1 WHERE field_2 = 1`

`SELECT count(id) from table_1 WHERE field_2 = 1`

Can this be done in a Single Query..
only one table is use but 3 outputs
like:

```
    count(id) | count(id) | count(id)<br>
    12        | 44        | 55
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use get the result by using an aggregate function with a CASE expression similar to the following:

```
select
  sum(case when field_1 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) field1Total,
  sum(case when field_2 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) field2Total
from table_1
```

You will add more `sum(case...)` expression for the remaining items that you want to total.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Distinct (Select Count(id) from table_1 where field1=1)as id1, (Select Count(id) from table_1 where field2=1)as id2  from table_1
```